# После сборки с помощью pyinstaller не отображается иконка. Что можно сделать?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, icon

У меня есть проект на Python. Используя pyinstaller собираю exe. По какой то причине не хочет устанавливаться иконка приложения. Расширение картинки ico. Сначала иконка лежала в папке со всеми ресурсами, но после безуспешных попыток указать путь к этой иконке решил положить ее в корень проекта. В идеале хотелось бы чтобы иконка лежала в папке с другими ресурсами.
Пробовал несколько вариантов указания иконки:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --icon=LOGO_BRIC.ico --add-data "for_exe_app;." --hidden-import "docx" create_pass.py
```

Так же пробовал так:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --i LOGO_BRIC.ico --add-data "for_exe_app;." --hidden-import "docx" create_pass.py
```

Так же пытался указать полный путь в файле spec таким образом:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


a = Analysis(
    ['create_pass.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('for_exe_app', '.')],
    hiddenimports=['docx'],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='create_pass',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
    icon=["D:\maxim\работа\jjj\passport_create\LOGO_BRIC.ico"],
)
```

Вроде все правильно делаю, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Попробуйте через auto py to exe собрать‍♀️

Comment: к сожалению мне для автоматизации процесса сборки нужен сборщик с консольным интерфейсом. Не графическим.

Comment: Auto py to exe использует под капотом pyinstaller, так что просто запустите auto py, выберите все нужные настройки и посмотрите какую команду для консольной сборки он вам предложит. А дальше сравните с тем как вы собираете.

Comment: Не знал об этой особенности auto py to exe, спасибо. Но проблема почему то это не решило. В выходной папке так и остается ехе без иконки, хотя auto py to exe выдает результат с иконкой. В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: Можете привести пример своей строки для сборки и вариант с ауто пай? И такой еще вопрос: вы кода через консоль собираете, переходите через cd в каталог с файлом и иконкой? Пробовали указать в командной строке полный путь к иконке?

Comment: pyinstaller --noconfirm --onedir --console --icon "D:/user/работа/jjj/project/for_exe_app/LOGO.ico" --add-data "D:/user/работа/jjj/project/for_exe_app;for_exe_app/"  "D:/user/работа/jjj/project/create_pass.py"
такую команду мне предложил auto py, я ее ввел у себя и сборка произошла без иконки. все пути указаны полностью.